# Добрый день, при установке kafka возникает проблема. В чем проблема?

Tags: apache-kafka

При выполнении команды .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties вылезает ошибка в консоли
""C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot/java"" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Прикладываю вывод моей java -version и переменных сред.
C:\kafka>java -version
java version "1.8.0_391"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_391-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.391-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

в переменных средах в Path указано следующее
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin

в JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot